# Can portable holes be stitched together to create a "portable room" that can be carried around?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I am rather new to D&D but have played 3 characters (different classes) before I had to leave my group. Now that I feel well enough to return, I am working on a new character who's a traveling mute merchant. Though I have a few wording issues on things like cart vs wagon, I am fascinated with portable holes and how they can be used. After searching a few sites (and finding great results on this one) I would like to ask for more details about the use of these holes. (looking at 5e)

The idea I've been having about portable holes is questioning if they can be used as more than just huge pockets, and how effective they can be as storage. I realize now that I cannot ask all the questions I have individually, so in an attempt to unify most of them allow me to ask this:

Knowing that you cannot cut, modify or stitch pocket holes together, would it be possible to craft a square hole that has been mounted to a tarp so that, when pulled taut on a frame, the hole can be used as a portable room, say creating a portable bedroom or medical room you can carry around with you on your adventures?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how things work around here. We have a one-question-per-post policy and this will get closed as too broad. Please [edit] the post to a single question to get it reopened. If you like you can ask the others in their own posts. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: These questions are definitely not silly or stupid.  But there *are* a lot of them! Try asking one question per post - it's totally o.k. to ask 5 separate questions about the same general topic.  If this post gets closed it will be because you have too many questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There's nothing in the rules to support it.

There are no secret rules in D&D, nothing hidden between the lines. The [Portable Hole](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/portable-hole) description is complete - it's six feet around, ten feet deep, and has to be deployed on a solid surface. Note that it isn't "huge pockets" - it's something you have to lay out, then climb down inside. It's not something that's really practical to use in combat.

### Work with your DM.

From some of the other questions, it sounds like you want to have a covered wagon that's bigger on the inside than the outside. Work with your DM. They're going to have to decide if such a thing is even appropriate to the world and the level of magic they envision.

Not to rain on your parade, but as an aside to your technical rules question... You may also want to consider what's good for interacting with a group. Being a merchant is not going to be a good fit for many campaigns. Sure, merchants exist in the campaign, but merchants are not generally *adventurers* and *adventuring* is what D&D is designed to portray. Mutism is also an issue: you'll need buy-in from the other players as much as the DM, because it makes their interactions with your character more difficult.

Comment: I read that clerics in the 3.5e could enchant to craft portable holes, which is one reason I was wondering about how stiff the rules were. 
As for being a merchant, though few, the campaigns I took part in had players able to make their own deals and marriages. This lead to some of us getting rich and most still struggling (the richest one held the bag of holding too). That's why I I didn't see anything wrong with picking up the extra dough on the side.

Comment: @VictorB D&D3.x had fairly robust magic item crafting rules. D&D5E does not.